# z-index не работает с position relative

Tags: html, css, css3, анимация

Я создал `fiddle` для демонстрации проблемы, но необходимо показать код и здесь.

Необходимо, чтобы `"hero" div` находился вверху другого (`overlap`) при наведении. 
Но при этом происходит смещение других `div` , поэтому я присвоил ему высокий `z-index` и `relative позиционирование`, но это не помогает.

Также может кто-нибудь сказать мне, как удалить линейный градиент из свойства фона `div` при наведении курсора, не указывая снова `background` в `:hover`.

```css
.holder {
  margin-top: 10vh;
  margin-left: 10vw;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  position: relative !important;
  z-index: 0;
}

.hero {
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-position: center !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative !important;
}

#first {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), url('https://i.imgur.com/86S4kU6.jpg');
}

#second {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), url('https://i.imgur.com/smyum62.jpg');
}

#third {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), url('https://i.imgur.com/1APBHId.jpg');
}

#fourth {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), url('https://i.imgur.com/a1zVpPz.jpg');
}

.hero:hover {
  z-index: 1000 !important;
  width: 27vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="hero" id="first"></div>
  <div class="hero" id="second"></div>
  <div class="hero" id="third"></div>
  <div class="hero" id="fourth"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aks30498/8waty2m9/27/

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/51301903/7394871

Answer (score 2):

`Gradient` и `image` устанавливаются с использованием того же свойства, которое является фоном, поэтому вы не можете справиться с этим, используя `z-index`.

Вы можете изменить `background-size`, чтобы скрыть градиент при наведении. Затем вы можете использовать `transform`, чтобы увеличить изображение и наложить другое:

*Я удалил ненужный код из вашего сниппета*

```css
.holder {
  margin-top: 10vh;
  margin-left: 10vw;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
}

.hero {
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#first {
  background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), url('https://i.imgur.com/86S4kU6.jpg');
}

#second {
  background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), url('https://i.imgur.com/smyum62.jpg');
}

#third {
  background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), url('https://i.imgur.com/1APBHId.jpg');
}

#fourth {
  background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), url('https://i.imgur.com/a1zVpPz.jpg');
}

.hero:hover {
  background-size: 0 0, cover;
  transform:scale(1.4);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="hero" id="first">

  </div>
  <div class="hero" id="second">

  </div>
  <div class="hero" id="third">

  </div>
  <div class="hero" id="fourth">

  </div>
</div>
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51302207/7394871)